# When and how to exit file uploader service

Tags: android

1. I have a class that implements fileuploader service. Activites bind to it and supply it a list of files to be uploaded, and then unbind immediately. The files are then uploaded one-by-one by the service in a background thread(asynctask).
2. I start this service in my dashboard actvity using startService(), so that it keeps running until specifically stopService() is called.
3. Now, my question is when do I stop this service?

Basically I need to check two conditions: 1: all files are uploaded; 2: app has exited.
Also, to exit the App, user has to press back button on dashboard activity.

I could have overrided back button press and queriesd the service whether any files are left, but I dont want to use that method.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe an `IntentService` would be a better fit for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Activites bind to it and supply it a list of files to be uploaded, and then unbind immediately.

I would recommend then using `startService()` rather than `bindService()`.

> The files are then uploaded one-by-one by the service in a background thread(asynctask).

This seems like a much better fit for `startService()` and an `IntentService` (or [a `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) perhaps, if you are concerned about the device falling asleep during uploads).

> I start this service in my dashboard actvity using startService()

This would not be needed if you used `startService()` for sending over the work.

> so that it keeps running until specifically stopService() is called.

Ideally, the service would shut itself down, like `IntentService` does. After all, only the service knows when the service is done.

> my question is when do I stop this service?

When you have no more work to do. `IntentService` does this automatically. If you really want to maintain your own thread pool for doing the work, then when your work queue is empty and all threads are done, call `stopSelf()` from within the service.

> Basically I need to check two conditions: 1: all files are uploaded

Yes.

> 2: app has exited

No. Your UI should not care whether the service is running or not running. The service should take care of itself.

> Also, to exit the App, user has to press back button on dashboard activity.

Users are welcome to leave your app however they please: BACK, HOME, RECENTS, a `Notification`, an incoming phone call, etc.

> Any suggestions?

Use an `IntentService`. Send over the jobs to be uploaded via calls to `startService()`, packaging all needed data into the `Intent` used with `startService()` (e.g., extras). Do your upload work in `onHandleIntent()`. If desired, use `LocalBroadcastManager` to let activities in your app know about the upload status, so they can reflect that in their UI if they so choose. `IntentService` will handle stopping itself when its work queue empties.

Comment: Thnx @CommonsWare. That was indeed a good answer. Im going with intent srvice.